# NextAuth redirection with t3 stack

Tags: next.js, next-auth, t3

I'm using a fresh T3 app with the NextJs app router.
I've configured NextAuth and added some providers.
Everything seems good, but after logging in, I'm always redirected to this link: `http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin`

That throws a 404 because this route doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.
When I manually go back to `http://localhost:3000`, I'm connected as expected.

Am I supposed to create this login page myself? Or configure something to specify a different endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your environment variable for `NEXTAUTH_URL` is defined without a string and the special characters in it are being misinterpreted after URL parsing.

To avoid this, you can use double quotes when defining environment variables, especially URLs where special characters may have different meanings based on context:

```bash
NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000"
# NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000 without quotes might be misinterpreted
```

After making this change, restart your Next.js development environment, and see if the redirection issue is resolved.